# React Hook UseState doen't set the value after calling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am implementing a React component to make payments. And there is a part in my code where I used useEffect to setValues from useState. The Code is as follows:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
  axiosFetch
    .get("auth/get_user")
    .then(res => {
      setUserName(res.data.name);
      setUserEmail(res.data.email);
      setUserContact(res.data.contact);
      console.log(res);
      console.log(userName);
      console.log(userEmail);
      console.log(userContact);
    })
    .catch(() => {})
  }, [])
```

When I run this code the browser prints console.log(res) as expected. But it prints the other three statements as Empty Strings (I expect some other values).

Here is what the console prints.

[image]

As you can see that console.log(res) is printing correctly. Then why not the other three??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Because setState is an async call, it will not apply immediately.

Comment: can I write it as userName = res.data.name ? What are the demerits of doing so?

Comment: @ParasBansal - That's just not how React works. I recommend going through some of the tutorials and documentation on https://reactjs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

The state is set asynchronously.

The variables won't have new values until the component is re rendered.

Setting them will trigger a rerender, but the useEffect callback (where you are logging the values) won't run again because none of its dependencies have changed.